# Writing a cell in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

This query might seem a bit childish, but this has been bugging me for quite a few days.
I am completely new to Microsoft Excel and want to know how do hold same values in two different excel cells?

> Example: Cell A1=bandwidth Cell E1=[minimum:bandwidth():utilization]
>   I want the word "bandwidth" to be same in both the cells. So if the user
>   inputs "bandwidth" into cell A1, then this generated into E1.

Kindly help me with this one.

Comment: Just add a formula into E1 that reads `=A1`?  No VBA required here at all to copy the value from one cell to the other.  Or is that not what you're after?  It's a little unclear.

Answer (score 0):

In **E1** enter the formula:

```
="minimum:" & A1 & "():utilization"
```

as you update **A1**, the displayed text in **E1** will follow.

Answer (score -1):

Adding to the solutions already given, you can define the format to be used for A1 with the TEXT function:

```
="minimum:" & TEXT(A1,"#,##0.00") & "():utilization"
```

Comment: what does "#,##0.00" stand for?

Comment: It gives you thousand separator and 2 decimals as a number format. See also [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4).